# How Talend can trigger the process chains in SAP APO system?

Tags: abap, talend, sap-bw, sap-apo

I am trying to trigger a process chain in **SAP APO system** using Talend. Is it possible to do so? I didn't find any supportive documentation regarding the same.

Comment: What kind of trigger do you want to use ? Is there an API in SAP that you can call ? (with a tRestClient for example). Could you write a triggering file in a folder listened by your SAP process ?

Comment: Well this question is more related to SAP side, whether using RFC BAPI we can trigger SAP process chain or not.As talend have specific components to pull/push data in/out from SAP system, is there any way to trigger process chains also using those components.

Comment: Do you have a subscription for Talend, or are you using Talend Open Studio ? Because I think some components and options (like tSAPBapi) are only available in the licensed product

Comment: I have a subscription for Talend, but from talend documentation i couldn't confirm whether we can trigger process chains or not.